# why could dict.get('',None) return a list in Python?

Tags: python

I am reading a sourse code and get some doubt.The 'config' here is a dict.

```
        server_port = config.get('server_port', None)
```

why could config.get('server_port', None) return a list ?

```
    if server_port:
        if type(server_port) == list:
            for a_server_port in server_port:
                config['port_password'][a_server_port] = config['password']
        else:
            config['port_password'][str(server_port)] = config['password']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "server_port" is the key for a list that is stored in the dict.

The "None" just specifies a default value in the case of a non-existent key- value pair.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dictionary

```
thing = {
    "name": "Bob,
    "height": 19,
}
```

you can request the value of a key with `thing.get()`

```
>>> thing.get("name")
Bob
```

`dict.get()` has a optional parameter `default=None` that is returned in the case that the key is not found within the dictionaries keys.

```
>>> thing.get("someUnknownKey")
None
```

but

```
>>> thing.get("someUnknownKey", default="If key is not found, print this")
If key is not found, print this
```

so `server_port` is a possible key within a dictionary, if is it not found, `None` is returned. If it is found, the `value` of key `server_port` is returned - which is expected to be a `list`.